# cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'games'

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm following a basic book learning XML. Following the book exactly and editing the XML slightly gave me this error:

```
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'games'.
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<games
  xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org game.xsd">
  <game>
    <title>Red Dead Redeption Two</title>
    <platform>Xbox One</platform>
    <desc>Red Dead Redeption Two is a western action adventure game</desc>
    <img>Cover.png</img>
  </game>
</games>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema games.xsd">

  <xs:element name="games">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="game" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="platform" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="desc" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="img" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Look at `<games`. See anything wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. When asking about a problem it's really important to reduce the code to the absolute smallest example that duplicates it. If you had done that you would have instantly seen the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### XSD

Change

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema games.xsd"
```

to

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

because the latter is the actual definition of the XMLSchema namespace, and the former appears to be a misguided attempt at following the form of a `schemaLocation` attribute.

Delete the following:

```
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
```

because the default namespace of the XSD should not be `http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd` and because the `mstns` namespace prefix declaration is not needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="games">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="game" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="platform" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="desc" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="img" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

### XML

Change

```
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"
```

to be

```
xmlns="http://tempuri.org"
```

to match both the `targetNamespace` in the XSD and the `schemaLocation` in the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<games
  xmlns="http://tempuri.org"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org games.xsd">
  <game>
    <title>Red Dead Redeption Two</title>
    <platform>Xbox One</platform>
    <desc>Red Dead Redeption Two is a western action adventure game</desc>
    <img>Cover.png</img>
  </game>
</games>
```

After making the above changes, your XML will validate against your XSD successfully.